# Where should I validate arguments? Factory Pattern, Java

Tags: java, validation, abstract-class, factory-method

Suppose I have an abstract class with an abstract builder, both of which get inherited by 3 separate subclasses:

```
public abstract class Role {

    protected string name;
    protected int propertyA;
    protected int propertyB;


    protected abstract static class RoleBuilder<T extends Role, B extends RoleBuilder<T,B>> {


        protected T role;
        protected B roleBuilder;

        protected abstract T getRole();
        protected abstract B thisBuilder();

        protected RoleBuilder(Hero h) {

            role = getRole();
            roleBuilder = thisBuilder();

            role.name = h.name;
            role.propertyA = h.propertyA; 
            role.propertyB = h.propertyB;

        }

        public T build() {
            return role;
        }

    }
}

 public class Healer extends Role {

    int propertyC;

    public Healer() {

    }

    public static final class HealerBuilder extends Role.RoleBuilder<Healer, HealerBuilder> {

        @Override protected Healer getRole() {
            return new Healer();
        }

        @Override protected HealerBuilder thisBuilder() {
            return this;
        }

        public HealerBuilder(Hero h) {
            super(h);
        }

        public HealerBuilder setPropertyC(int i) {
            role.propertyC = i;
            return roleBuilder;
        }

     }
}
```

I instantiate the healer class (and the other two subclasses) using enums methods within the enums, like so:

```
public enum RoleTypes {
    BRUISER{
    ...
    },
    DAMAGE_DEALER {
    ...
    },
    HEALER {

        public Healer getRole(Hero h) {
            return new Healer.HealerBuilder(h) 
                    .setPropertyC(h.getC);
                    .build();
        }

    };

    abstract Role getRole(Hero h);
}
```

Where should I be validating arguments for the creation of these objects?

- Within the abstract class constructor (should I validate Hero object properties, or can I assume that object is "safe" if its properties are validated on creation?) and subclass builder methods?
- Within the enum methods?
- Within the factory method that calls RoleType.getRole(h), used by the rest of my application to actually create objects of type Role?

Comment: The rule of thumb is to check any publicly passed parameters, but you can skip these that are internal to your package and you are sure they're OK

Comment: So if I keep the builders & RoleTypes enum package-private & validate my arguments within the Factory Method, which is the only publically accessible one within the package, I should be good to go?